# Paypal IPN 1.1 php script seems to loop through several times

Tags: loops, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have recently updated my IPN script for the new 1.1 version. It works and payments go through but it is running my success code (inserting into db, sending emails) multiple times. e.g. I did a test purchase and my order went through 22 times and i received 22 emails?!?

This is my exact code (the actual db and mailing code is straight forward - no loops at all):

```
//read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

//post back to PayPal system to validate (replaces old headers)
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//

//error connecting to paypal
if (!$fp) {
   //
}

//successful connection    
if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        $res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT

        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) {

            //insert into db and send an email goes here

        }

        if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID" ) == 0) {   }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Just a little bit more best practice formatting and you'd problably see the problem yourself.

Comment: ok...it looks formatted ok to me now (I indented that }). I still can't see the problem though

Comment: It has to be the while() loop running round and round but I don't understand why it would run through more than once? This is the same code most people are using

Comment: try error_reporting(-1) at the top of the script and see what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
$arrRequestVars=$_POST;

$cx=stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http"=>array(
            "method"=>"POST",
            "header"=>"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "content"=>"cmd=_notify-validate&".http_build_query($arrRequestVars),
        ),
        "tls"=>array(
            "allow_self_signed"=>false,
        ),
        "ssl"=>array(
            "allow_self_signed"=>false,
        ),
    )
);
$strPayPalVerifyResponse=file_get_contents("https://".PAYPAL_API_HOSTNAME."/cgi-bin/webscr", false, $cx);
if(is_string($strPayPalVerifyResponse))
{
    $_arrParts=explode(" ", $http_response_header[0]);
    $nHTTPResponseCode=(int)$_arrParts[1];
    if($nHTTPResponseCode!==200)
        throw new Exception("Failed to verify wether request originated from PayPal. HTTP response code: ".$nHTTPResponseCode);

    if(trim($strPayPalVerifyResponse)=="INVALID")
        throw new Exception("PayPal did not recognize/validate the incoming IPN request. If the request was valid then mark as paid manually.");
    else if(trim($strPayPalVerifyResponse)!="VERIFIED")
        throw new Exception("Failed to verify wether request originated from PayPal. PayPal response: ".$strPayPalVerifyResponse);
}
else
    throw new Exception("Failed to verify wether request originated from PayPal.");
```

This is an as few as possible dependencies example. I recommend cURL over file_get_contents.